# Make a bootstrap search box functional on blogger

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, blogger, search-box

I'm trying to replace my webpage's navbar from the *Blogger* default to the bootstrap one. I modified the example to only have a search box in the navbar but it **doesn't** search. How do I do?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></input>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ariloc/auu1L19k/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ari Fi.
 you need to add few more Attribute for blogger search to work.
In `<form>` add `method="get" action="/search"`
In `<input>` add `name='q'`
see the code below

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <form  method="get" action="/search" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input name='q' type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></input>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot some of important parts of the form method and action. try this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form id="searchbox" method="get" action="/search" autocomplete="off" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <input name='q' type="text" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
            <button id="button-submit" type="submit" value=" " class="btn btn-default" />
        </form>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. My webpage's link changes with a /search at the end but nothing happen.